# Variable error and cannot convert to boolean error

Tags: java

So I’ve bolded were the errors are happening but I don’t understand why they are happening. It doesn’t make sense to me.

```
    for(int i = 1; i < Array.getLength(purchases);i++)
    {
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Enter a price for item #"+i+": $");
        double temp3=input.nextDouble();
        double price=temp3;

            if(price=>0) **<==it wont let me have both = and >**
            {
                total=total+price;
                double temp1=total*100;
                int temp2=(int)temp1;
                total=temp2/100.0;
        System.out.print("That was $"+price+". Your total is $"+total);
            }
       else(price==0) **<=="The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"**
            {

            }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use bold with code formatting, now the code is messed up by formatting

Answer (score 2):

```
if(price=>0)
```

This should be: -

```
if(price >= 0)
```

Note the order of `>` and `=`. `>` comes first.

And also: - `else(price==0)` should just be `else`, you don't need to add a condition in your `else`.

Comment: @TylerDManary.. haha :) Well, certainly, given that you are doing these kinds of errors.

Comment: i wonder how many more times i would have over looked that if i had not of asked

Answer (score 1):

your **greater than or equal to** ordering is wrong.

```
if(price=>0)
```

should be

```
if(price>=0)
```

the correct ordering is  to use `>=`

```
 else(price==0)
```

should be

```
 else if(price<0) //should be less than zero , because you are already checking if price is >=0 in your if.
```

or just **else** would **suffice**

**nested if-else syntax**:

```
  if(somecond){

   }
   else if(somecond){
    }
   else{ // you don't mention any condition for else, as it would be the last condition.

    }
```

Comment: Note that, your else if condition is already covered in your if. Just `else` would work.

Comment: @GanGnaM.. Well, in that case, your `else if` will never get executed. It tests for condition `==`, and your if already has a condition `>=` which will itself check for `==`.

Comment: So, either it should be `else if(price < 0)` which seems useless, so just `else`.

Comment: @RohitJain i just realised, else should check if price is lessthan 0 .as he's already checking in if price >=0. :P

Comment: @RohitJain dude, if you dont mind. its 1:00 AM in india i suppose, go to bed :P

Comment: @GanGnaM.. Lol :) I'm on bed only. Just thought to check out some posts on SO before sleep -> which is really not coming. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19716/discussion-between-gangnamstyleoverflowerror-and-rohit-jain)

Answer (score 0):

In java, "greater than or equal to" is >=.
Also, for the second error, you should have "else if", not just "else."